# Connection Timeout Disconnects using Zehon FTP

Tags: coldfusion, ftp

I am using the Zehon FTP utility on a ColdFusion 9 server. When I am FTP'ing files, it creates one directory, transfers about 16 files, then gives the message :

```
com.zehon.exception.FileTransferException: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: Could not connect to FTP server on "ftpservername.com".
```

Here's the code:

```
    <cfscript>
//FTP server information
host = "#getSiteList.TMS_FTPADDRESS#";
username = "#getSiteList.TMS_USERNAME#";
password = "#getSiteList.TMS_PASSWORD#";


/* sendingFolder = Folder whose content is to be uploaded recursively
*  to the FTP server.
*/
sendingFolder = "#local_Folder#";

/* Forward slash / = root dir of FTP server.
*  if you wish to FTP to privateDir under the root, for example,
*  then set destFolder to "/privateDir"
*/
destFolder = "/#parent_Folder#";
FTP = createObject("java", "com.zehon.ftp.FTP");
thisBatchTransferProgressDefault= createObject("java", "com.zehon.BatchTransferProgressDefault").init();
FileTransferStatus = createObject("java", "com.zehon.FileTransferStatus");
try {
   status = FTP.sendFolder(sendingFolder, destFolder, thisBatchTransferProgressDefault, host, username, password);
    if(FileTransferStatus.SUCCESS is status){
        writeOutput(sendingFolder & " got ftp-ed successfully to folder " & destFolder);
    }
    else if(FileTransferStatus.FAILURE is status){
        writeOutput("Failed to ftp to folder " & destFolder);
    }
} catch (any e) {
   writeOutput(e.message);
}   
</cfscript>
```

I tried this on two different servers and the same issue. If I use FileZilla or CFFTP, I can transfer all my files (CFFTP is having issues creating subfolders, which is why I moved away from that, and we want our customers to use their web app to FTP files, not a client). Has anyone else experience this? If so, was a solution discovered? Thanks

Comment: Did you try to switch between Active/Passive Mode?

Comment: Alexander, I am going through the docs and I cannot see how to set active/passive.

Comment: http://www.zehon.com/javadocs/com/zehon/ftps/FTPsClient.html#setPassive(boolean) ?

Comment: Alexander, I meant I cannot see how to add it to my code. I a using it in a CFSCRIPT tag.  I am assuming it goes somewhere in this line?  status = FTP.sendFolder(sendingFolder, destFolder, thisBatchTransferProgressDefault, host, username, password);

Comment: Why don't you edit the relevant code snippet into your question, so everyone can have a look?

Comment: You said it works using FileZilla, check the connection settings to the FTP there. The static FTP class you are using establishes a connection using passive mode by default, which is usually the safest option (due to Firewall). However, maybe your FTP server expects active mode. `cfftp` defaults to active mode if you did not specify `passive="true"`, so if `cfftp` at least connects for you, active mode is where it's at.